# How do I project the screen of my Android phone for a presentation?

Tags: screen-sharing

How can I project my Droid Incredible screen so I can demonstrate the smart phone to a room full of people?

Does anyone know how I can link the phone to a PC? To a TV?

Comment: Here's a list of alternatives that do that [https://duckduckgo.com/?q=alt! apowermirror](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=alt!%20apowermirror)

Comment: there are many apps which share the screen, is this question meant also for functionality of presentations available from the PC/TV I understood the question to just be asking for screen sharing. There are many apps which share the screen e.g. [Screen Meet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projector.screenmeet), [Facebook Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca) and more. If I get no answer soon I will opt to change the formulation of the question and add my answer.

Answer (score 24):

For Android 5.0+ there is [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) is an open-source screen mirroring solution.

- developer mode and adb enabled required
- root **not** required
- scrcpy uses a server app on the device and a client app on your GNU/Linux, MacOS, or Windows machine.
- works over a USB cable or TCP/IP for WiFi scenarios
- supports cropping, recording, multiple devices
- allows for remote control of Android device from PC
- **NEW** As of 2.0 supports audio forwarding on Android 11+ (see [blog post](https://blog.rom1v.com/2023/03/scrcpy-2-0-with-audio/) or [github doc](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/doc/audio.md) for details)

Download pre-built binaries at above link.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that this does more than simply mirror your screen: you can actually control your phone entirely through your computer. This is very useful if your screen completely dies and you need to access your phone.

Comment: this is the ultimate solution for me as a Linux user, fast to install easy to run with native adb in android studio. 
As previous comment states it allows to contro the phone which is even better than simple screen share and ultimate for the presentation stand ups. 
Only drawback i have found is that it has issue with running along other adb virtualized devices - but thats probably just about a config. 
Running it with simple "scrcpy" command in console nothing more

Answer (score 20):

You can use this project to connect to control and see your phone from your desktop computer:
<s>http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/</s>
https://xsavikx.github.io/AndroidScreencast/

All you need is <s>the Android SDK installed and</s> an app OS-bundle (use one from the [latest release](https://github.com/xSAVIKx/AndroidScreencast/releases/latest)) and a phone that you can use in debug mode over the USB port. Next you can run the screencast right from your browser if you have the java plugin, just open the jnlp link: [androidscreencast.jnlp](https://xsavikx.github.io/AndroidScreencast/jnlp/androidscreencast.jnlp). You can also download it and run in a terminal with `javaws androidscreencast.jnlp`.

Comment: I tried it and it seems you cannot control the device from the PC if the phone is not rooted. But you can use the phone and see the screen in real time on the PC, which I think is exactly what you want to do. You can then connect your PC to a TV or a projector for a larger screen.

Comment: You need root to use this :)

Comment: worked perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 7):

**screenrecord**

`screenrecord` is an internal Android executable that dumps screen to a file, and `ffplay` from ffmpeg happens to be able to play an H.264 encoded stream from stdin

First [enable ADB USB access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213874/how-to-configure-adb-access-for-android-devices).

Then, put your Android screen in landscape mode to fill the entire desktop display (not like in the portrait demo below), and then on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install adb ffmpeg    
adb exec-out screenrecord --output-format=h264 - |
   ffplay -fs -framerate 60 -probesize 32 -sync video  -
```

You might have to make the screen move a bit before you see anything:

[image]

Uncut demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVgeoMYm61Q

Explanation of parameters:

- `-probesize 32 -framerate 60 -sync video` reduce the delay between the image on the phone and the image on the disktop (thanks to [@arbuz](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7686/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-devices-screen-live-on-pc-through-adb/154328#comment245597_154328))
- we use `adb exec-out` instead of `adb shell` because shell might [mess up some control characters due to being a shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578416/read-binary-stdout-data-from-adb-shell/31401447#31401447) (thanks to [@Bowi](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7686/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-devices-screen-live-on-pc-through-adb/154328#comment303176_154328))
- `-fs`: start `-ffplay` in fullscreen

See also: [Use adb screenrecord command to mirror Android screen to PC via USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472962)

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04, Android 11, Pixel 3a.

Answer (score 2):

Per the idea of using a TV (or projector) specifically, many devices can do this pretty easily using some kind of digital audio/video output connector. Some devices have micro or mini HDMI ports, which could be used with a proper cable to connect to any HDMI receiver. Others support the [MHL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_High-definition_Link) standard, which does the same thing but via the USB/charging port. Still others (notably Samsung's tablet lineup) use a proprietary dock connector, but have appropriate composite or digital output cables available.

Typically, support for any of these will be noted in the device's specs, so if outputting content to a TV/projector is an important feature then you'll want to simply examine the spec sheet for such information. For the HTC Incredible specifically, you can get a [micro-USB to composite cable.](http://shop.htcpedia.com/htc-micro-usb-tv-out-cable.html?compability_product=757)

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Mobizen](https://www.mobizen.com/en/) app to share my Android mobile screen on a computer screen. The new web browser version is convenient for presentations because it lets you stream any multimedia from your phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply:

1. install [Team Viewer Quick Support](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market) on your phone
2. and then connect on it from **Team Viewer** Client on your PC

Answer (score 1):

I tried AndroidScreencast and Droid@Screen but they were very laggy.

I had success with https://www.vysor.io/, in free version it's ad supported (once every half an hour) and is limited to the lowest quality (which occasionally produces artifacts). But overall it let me do a presentation without any issues.

I just downloaded the Chrome extension and it took care of everything, the setup was quick and easy (even though I'm on Ubuntu).

Comment: I use vysor as well and if you except the 1 ad every half an hour it is very good! You can also control your phone through your pc.

Answer (score 1):

You can e.g. do so via open-source app [ScreenStream](https://github.com/dkrivoruchko/ScreenStream) (available on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.dvkr.screenstream) or [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/info.dvkr.screenstream/)) if you want to access it via a network (wifi).

### Access via USB/ADB

`adb` can thankfully forward network sockets. So:

1. Enable "listen on localhost" in the settings ("advanced" section) of this app. (You can even disable anything else.)
2. Run `adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080` (syntax: `adb forward tcp:LOCAL tcp:DEVICE`) or another port you have set in the settings to forward the connection.
3. Now you can access this on your computer with `127.0.0.1:8080`.

Run `adb forward --remove-all` to remove that again.

---

**Alternatively** you can e.g. [use adb alone on KitKat or higher as it has a built-in screenrecord feature](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7686/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-devices-screen-live-on-pc-through-adb/154328#154328), but you need a player on your device then. (no simple web access possible.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the TeamViewer tool. You have to install the Android part (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile) and the desktop/laptop part (http://www.teamviewer.com). Then your computer has to be connected to a video projector or something like that.

TeamViewer is free for non-office use and pretty smart.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would solve the OP's problem. TeamViewer will let you control your PC from an Android device, but not vice versa. In order to use the PC to project your phone's screen you'd need the opposite (a way to view and control Android from the PC).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.
TeamViewer allow you to view Android device screen (and take control) from your PC too.
I use the "TeamViewer QuickSupport" app for that.
As my laptop can be connected to a video projector I'm able to do some demo during meeting.
Cheers
Thomas

Comment: Hi again,
Free status for this type of usage need to be investigated ...
Currently I use it in a Company with paid version so I can't be absolutly certain.
Sorry
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bigscreen Broadcast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ideasynthesis.roguesavant.bigscreen.camera) ($0.99 on Google Play). It doesn't require any rooting, and you can install it right from the Google Play store. It enables you to project your Android screen (any app) and your Android cameras (both front and back) to a ChromeCast, or to a free [Mac companion viewer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bigscreen-broadcast-viewer/id999845263?mt=12).

For full disclosure — my brother built this after the functionality was released in Android and I figured I'd help him find people who were looking for this functionality!