# Is there a way to see the device's screen *live* on PC, through ADB?

Tags: usb, adb, camera, htc-desire-hd, screen-sharing

I am a vlogger and after getting HTC Desire HD, found out its camera was all I ever needed. However, I usually have to see myself while recording video, to control my facial expressions, and with a rear-facing camera it's just not possible.

I know ADB allows for screenshots, but is there a way to *stream* the screen output to my PC's display? 
Not necessarily at 20+ fps, just a couple frames per second will do.

Comment: Is this question really a duplicate? The other one only asks on how to mirror screen. This one asks to do that **via ADB** specifically

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the [Android Screencast](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/) app.

See the [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=557717) for more details.

Comment: Looks nice and answers the question I put in my thread's title... But ironically, displays the black bar instead of camera output. I guess it's like print-screening Windows Media Player: you end up with everything except the video itself :(

Comment: I'm not sure why you got that problem, but even if it worked appropriately it only gives you a 4-5 fps refresh rate, which is far from "Live".

Comment: I doubt you will be able to pipe output from your phone's camera to another device.  Have you tried a more hardware based approach, like setting up a mirror? :)

Answer (score 46):

**screenrecord**

`screenrecord` is an internal Android executable that dumps screen to a file, and `ffplay` from ffmpeg happens to be able to play an H.264 encoded stream from stdin

First [enable ADB USB access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213874/how-to-configure-adb-access-for-android-devices) and then on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install adb ffmpeg    
adb exec-out screenrecord --output-format=h264 - |
   ffplay -framerate 60 -probesize 32 -sync video  -
```

You might have to make the screen move a bit before you see anything:

[image]

Uncut demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVgeoMYm61Q

Explanation of parameters:

- `-probesize 32 -framerate 60 -sync video` reduce the delay between the image on the phone and the image on the disktop (thanks to [@arbuz](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7686/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-devices-screen-live-on-pc-through-adb/154328#comment245597_154328))
- we use `adb exec-out` instead of `adb shell` because shell might [mess up some control characters due to being a shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578416/read-binary-stdout-data-from-adb-shell/31401447#31401447) (thanks to [@Bowi](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7686/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-devices-screen-live-on-pc-through-adb/154328#comment303176_154328))

See also: [Use adb screenrecord command to mirror Android screen to PC via USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472962)

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04, Android 11, Pixel 3a.

Comment: The video starts faster with smaller probesize. I got good results with `ffplay -framerate 60 -probesize 32 -sync video  -` the "-framerate 60" removes the delay effect and "-sync video" drops the frames instead of fast forwading them.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I didn't want to install an app just to grab a screenshot when security policies were restricting it. For the record, it worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 with Android 7.0.

Comment: @b_laoshi great, added the new working versions report to the answer.

Comment: Anyone knows if this could be made working on Windows? In PowerShell I ran `adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264 - | ffplay -framerate 60 -probesize 32 -sync video -` but no preview window appears. `adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264 -` seems to work fine to stdout.

Comment: @Constructor basic question, does `ffplay` work at all on your system? E.g. with a regular mp4 :-)

Comment: Yes it did! Admittedly I don't use ffplay every day, but when I did `ffplay some.mkv` it works with a basic preview window (some video information: `Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1296x972, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)`, so it seems h264 is not the issue)

Comment: @Constructor OK. Gotta debug further then. E.g. ensure stdout is going out and into ffplay compare that with input from file.

Comment: Addition: You should use `adb exec-out ...` instead of `adb shell ...`, the latter seems to modify data for interactive shell purposes while `exec-out` doesn't.

Comment: @Bowi thanks for this info, can you provide a thread talking about that in more detail? E.g. providing a sample specific output sequence that gets modified?

Comment: @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功, this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31401447/6403504 and, basing on it, this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13587203/6403504

Comment: Got it working on macOS Big Sur with Pixel 4 and Pixel 2. Awesome solution

Comment: Sample command to play with the [IINA](https://iina.io) player: `adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264 - | iina --stdin --keep-running --mpv-framerate=30 --mpv-untimed --mpv-framedrop=no --mpv-correct-pts=no`

Comment: There is a limit of 3 minutes using the screenrecord command. You can use a loop to continuously run the command and stop the stream from freezing.

`adb exec-out "while true; do screenrecord --output-format=h264 -; done" |
   ffplay -flags low_delay -framerate 60 -probesize 32 -sync video -an -
`

Answer (score 1):

Some Android phones have TV Out capabilities, usually through [USB](http://androidandme.com/2010/04/news/droid-incredible-does-tv-out-video/) or [HDMI](http://androidandme.com/2010/05/news/hands-on-hdmi-out-with-the-sprint-evo/), but sometimes through the [3.5 audio jack](http://androidandme.com/2010/07/news/samsung-galaxy-s-does-video-out-via-3-5-mm-headset-jack/). I don't think HTC Desire has any TV-Out capability though.

Answer (score -1):

Airdroid is all you need.  Simple and easy to use. You're able to see your camera out put live but for some reason not able to record it. Your pc and android phone must be on the same WiFi network.

Comment: *Airdroid* works over WiFi AFAIK. OP wanted a solution for ADB (via USB). He also wanted to see the device screen *live*, i.e. with no or just marginal delay. If not added recently, *Airdroid* doesn't support that IMHO.