# stream screen to pc

Tags: screen, stock-android, touchscreen, streaming, broken-screen

My phone screen is broken and i can't access my data etc. on it anymore since touch and screen don't work. I'm wondering if it's possible to plug it onto an pc and stream the screen to my pc (without an app installed on the phone.) just like downloading an os from pc to android. It's a samsung galaxy s advance. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I project the screen of my Android phone for a presentation?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/how-do-i-project-the-screen-of-my-android-phone-for-a-presentation)

Answer (score 1):

If its just data you are concerned about then you don't even need to mirror your phones screen on your computer. You can use a development tool called [ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html), this will allow you to simply connect your phone through USB and access the filesystem.

There is plenty of documentation online about ADB, but if you need any specifics for what to do let me know in a comment.

Comment: I echo Colin's advice to use ADB. Additionally, a mirroring application would be useless if you can't use touch input on the phone, and to interact with it you'd need to connect additional peripheral devices (ie. Keyboard/mouse) to even interact with your phone. ADB lets you send commands to the phone from your computer. The only issue is that you'd have to learn how to use it from a command line interface, but anyone can do anything they set their mind to. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

While using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) (see its [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for details) is a good idea, you would need to have [usb-debugging](/questions/tagged/usb-debugging) enabled to be capable of using it. There are ways to do that (see our [broken-screen tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info)), though. But there are also alternatives:

For the display, you could use HDMI (or an HML to HDMI adapter) to have it "mirrored" to e.g. your TV or Laptop. For input, you could use an USB mouse/keyboard, assuming your device can operate as "OTG host" (there are [some apps to check that](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_storagemedia#group_534) – but checking this way would be a chicken-and-egg thingy; easier to just go ahead and try the real thing).

If all those steps work out, you should have a full display and input back, and could do with your device whatever you wish: Streaming, copying, using it as a "NAS", Webcam, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g. do so via [ScreenStream](https://github.com/dkrivoruchko/ScreenStream) if you want to access it via a network (wifi).

### Access via USB/ADB

`adb` can thankfully forward network sockets. So:

1. Enable "listen on localhost" in the settings ("advanced" section) of this app. (You can even disable anything else.)
2. Run `adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080` (syntax: `adb forward tcp:LOCAL tcp:DEVICE`) or another port you have set in the settings to forward the connection.
3. Now you can access this on your computer with `127.0.0.1:8080`.

Run `adb forward --remove-all` to remove that again.

---

**Alternatively** you can e.g. [use adb alone on KitKat or higher as it has a built-in screenrecord feature](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7686/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-devices-screen-live-on-pc-through-adb/154328#154328), but you need a player on your device then. (no simple web access possible.)