# How can I stream my android phone screen to my laptop computer?

Tags: video, streaming

I am mostly trying to solve a low resolution problem when watching Google Play movies as on my Windows 8.1 PC many of them are not available in HD quality. As Android phones have access to higher resolutions, but I have a better screen on my laptop, I was wondering how I could stream video content from my (unrooted) phone to my laptop screen.

I am aware of some DLNA solutions but as far as I know, they do not allow streaming of Google Play movies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to see the device's screen \*live\* on PC, through ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7686/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-devices-screen-live-on-pc-through-adb)

Comment: I don't think it's quite the same question, because of the extra complexity added by the copy protection functionality (i.e. "secure surface")

Comment: @DanHulme recommend making it clearer on title so Googlers will find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for screen mirroring apps like these:

- [Screen Stream Mirroring](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobzapp.screenstream)
- [AirDroid - Android on Computer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid)

Here is the [tutorial video on YouTube](http://youtube.com/watch?v=cWtxZgo0N-Q)

Comment: Thanks! I checked both of them but they do not seem to work well for an unrooted phone. AirDroid requires root and the other app requires you to enter developer mode and run a fairly lengthy startup procedure each time you restart your phone (plus it doesn't work for many people even after they do).

Comment: Yes bluestacks seems like a good workaround, hopefully there will be a more easier ways to mirror screen in the future. Thanks!