# How to capture video stream from Android phone screen and show it on laptop?

Tags: screencast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I project the screen of my android phone for a presentation?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/how-do-i-project-the-screen-of-my-android-phone-for-a-presentation)

How to capture video stream from Android phone screen and show it on laptop? I've got Android 2.2 device.

I need this to show how my application work on the conference in real time. Something like IPhone presentation on Mac World.

Comment: Have you considered installing the Android emulator on your laptop and just running the app on there?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this one is mentioned in the question Al linked to above, but I've used [Droid@Screen](http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/) to demo things at my office with pretty good success. It probably only gets around 10-15 FPS or so if I was going to take a guess at frame rate, but it appears a bit more smooth than the other options I've tried (including Android Screencast and a VNC connection).

Answer (score 2):

I just read [a review of Screen Cast & Screen Recorder](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/09/03/new-app-review-screen-cast-screen-recorder-makes-capturing-smooth-high-fps-video-of-your-rooted-devices-screen-a-breeze/) that's pretty compelling.  It requires root, like any on-device solution I'm aware of, but can record decent quality video at up to 30 FPS.  The review has example captures from various games and the videos are good enough for most anything you'd want, unless you need HD video for some reason.  The review didn't focus as much on the screencasting aspect, but if you need to screencast something at high quality then this app might be a good bet.  The app has a free trial so I definitely recommend trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

One option I know of is [Android Screencast](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/). But it only gets about 2-3FPS. This is because of the amount of time it takes to request the framebuffer. I have been working on a tool similar to this, but the most I have been able to get was about 7-9FPS (but its not available, nor is is "ready", for prime-time).

Another option would be using a [VNC server](http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-server/) on the device and a [VNC Viewer](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/winvncviewer.html) on the laptop. But again, you will have very low FPS with this too.