# How to play android games on PC?

Tags: applications, windows, emulators

I have Asphalt 6 on my HTC Desire S. That looks awesome on phone, now I want to play the game on PC. Is it possible at all? I mean is there any app which will let me play this game on my PC over wifi using my phone?

Desire S don't have any TV out, but it do support DLNA connection, if that matters.

OS: Windows XP
Mobile OS: Android 2.3.3

Answer (score 6):

As far as I'm aware, the official emulator would be too slow for most intensive games like Asphalt.  For games I usually use [Memu](http://www.memuplay.com/) on Windows and [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) on OSX/Linux (the latter also works on Windows, but Memu is definitely better).  I have found Bluestacks to be very buggy and do not recommend it.

For viewing the phone's screen from your PC you could use a solution from this question: [How to capture video stream from Android phone screen and show it on laptop?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-capture-video-stream-from-android-phone-screen-and-show-it-on-laptop).  You might be able to get up to 30 FPS depending on the quality.

One way to control the game externally, if you don't want to hold the phone, is to attach it to a gaming steering wheel.  Sort of like the WiiMote steering wheel attachment.

Answer (score 2):

You might have to fidget with this one, and if you could get it working, it would be awesome. There's an [Android x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) project that you could use to boot android on your computer, and just play the games there. The builds they have up now come with a few games, and if you could install .apk files to it, then you could play all the games right there!

Let us know if you do this, and how well it works!

Answer (score 1):

If you had a pretty decent PC, you could try using the official [Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) from the Android SDK. The only problem might be that with the current emulator, there is no graphic acceleration yet so game performance might not be so great, though Google says it will be coming soon.