# How can I view my phone's screen on a computer in real time?

Tags: screen-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I project the screen of my android phone for a presentation?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/how-do-i-project-the-screen-of-my-android-phone-for-a-presentation)
>   [How to capture video stream from Android phone screen and show it on laptop?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-capture-video-stream-from-android-phone-screen-and-show-it-on-laptop)

I have made a demo app and it's installed on my phone. I want to be able to show the app in action from my phone using a projector.

The way I see this happening is if I can share my phone's screen with my laptop. Is there an app to help me do that?

Note: The main reason for me not to use the Android device emulator is that it runs extremely slow and at 100% of CPU usage which I don't think is good for my laptop. I have a moderately spec-ed machine, and I need to find a why to do.

Answer (score 2):

do check

http://www.mightypocket.com/2010/08/android-screenshots-screen-capture-screen-cast/

http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/

Answer (score 2):

One that I have used is [Webkey](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.webkey). It requires root.