# Show desktop of Android box on PC ala TeamViewer

Tags: teamviewer, airdroid

How do I look at the dekstop of an Android box (that's connected to a HDMI display) on a PC?

AirDroid comes very close, but it does not let the user manipulate the desktop. All other apps that I came across accessed Windows desktop from an Android device. I want it the other way around; something like TeamViewer.

Comment: What is an Android box? Is that a cellphone?

Comment: No. It is a box that is connected to a hdmi display. Similar to a computer cabinet that is connected to a monitor.

Comment: What's wrong with TeamViewer? Isn't it free for personal use, and does what you want?

Comment: [How can I view my phone's screen on a computer in real time?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20199/how-can-i-view-my-phones-screen-on-a-computer-in-real-time) sounds like it describes what you're trying to accomplish (which is itself linked to a few other questions).

Comment: @eldarerathis Would that work for a phone? I think he's talking about an Android box? Possibly an Android TV box?

Comment: Thats right. I am talking of android tv box. And teamviewer doesn't let me access the android screen from a pc.

Comment: I have come across droid VNC server to accomplish what I want. This would be perfect except that it requires root.