# How to plug in an  Android Tablet and show it's screen on PC or Laptop for training session?

Tags: hdmi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I project the screen of my android phone for a presentation?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/how-do-i-project-the-screen-of-my-android-phone-for-a-presentation)

I just bought an Android Tablet, Toshiba Thrive AT100, its HDMI port make me able to plugged it directly to HDMI-support projector in my training session.

But I wonder if there is any application which allow me to do this kind of activity...

- Plugged Android Tablet to my laptop via HDMI (or any port), then show real-time tablet display on my laptop (or PC). This could be show via the application's area itself.

With this function, I can just switch from my presentation to show real using on tablet without to switch the cord between my laptop and my tablet.

Do you know this kind of application or any technique to do this?

Comment: You want a VNC server for Android. They are available, but this is off-topic on superuser.com. This question should be migrated to android stack exchange site.

Answer (score 1):

Try a vnc server for your tablet, if you have rooted it. Thats the free option.

Answer (score 1):

Most projectors have more than one input port; perhaps one HDMI and one VGA is a common arrangement, and there is usually a functionality to switch between HDMI and VGA on the projector. If you can arrange such that your laptop uses the VGA port and the Android uses the HDMI port (or vice versa) then you can use the projector's switching functionality.

It is also possible to use an HDMI switcher, such as this one [http://www.amazon.com/Ultra-High-Performance-Switcher-Switch/dp/B0015YWKYY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0015YWKYY)

For a software-only solution, you can use VNC; although you'll need a rooted device. With VNC, you can display the Android's screen in a window on your laptop, and you won't need to use HDMI cable.