# Record android screen

Tags: lg-gt540-optimus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Software or Device to present Application on Screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/12262/1465)
>   [How to plug in an  Android Tablet and show it's screen on PC or Laptop for training session?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/16806/1465)
>   [How do I project the screen of my Android phone for a presentation?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/5652/1465)
>   [How to capture video stream from Android phone screen and show it on laptop?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/10811/1465)

I am planning to make a screencast of my phone screen.

I need to know a way to record the screen

Please note that the Screencast & Screencapture app won't work, as I only have an armv6 processor.

Comment: We have a few questions on this, please check them out.  If none of the solutions work on arm v6 then flag this and we'll re-open.