# How to remotely share Motorola Xoom screen

Tags: screen-sharing

Is it  possible to remotely share my Xoom screen over the Internet?  For example, say I was at my house and wanted to share the screen with a friend in another town.  How would I got about it?

Comment: Can you check the questions listed as duplicates in [this post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18621/record-android-screen) and see if any of their answers will work for you?

Comment: These seem to be helpful, my question differs in the fact that I would like to screen cast remotely.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Android VNC server](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.onaips.vnc&hl=en) on your tablet, it should do the work...

Comment: This seems like the best choice that I've come across.  I was hoping to find a solution without rooting the device though :/

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [CatVision.io](https://www.catvision.io), it doesn't require rooting of the device etc. Works with Android 5.0+.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of this software.*