# Record android screen Droid Razr

Tags: motorola-droid-razr, screencast

I've been trying to connect my Droid Razr running 4.0.4 to record its screen, but have had no luck. I've tried VNC server, Tight VNC, and just tried the android adk using the adb or monitor tools, and nothing. I did list devices in adb, checked see devices in android debug monitor, and noticed that my device was not there. I have USB debugging and connected as media device when USB is pluged in.

Can anyone help me with this, so I can use something to record my screen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Record android screen](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18621/record-android-screen)

Comment: Better duplicate (when you follow the dup chain to its end): http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/how-do-i-project-the-screen-of-my-android-phone-for-a-presentation

Comment: Debugging this would be easier with more information. What happened when you tried to use the various VNC solutions (i.e what was the specific problem)? What steps did you take when trying to configure them?