# How to mirror Android phone on Mac or Windows for application presentation?

Tags: screen-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I project the screen of my android phone for a presentation?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/how-do-i-project-the-screen-of-my-android-phone-for-a-presentation)

Can anyone suggest some tools which can mirror an Android phone to a PC or a Mac?

I found some apps, but mostly they are remote desktop apps. They bring desktop screens to the phone. However, I want it the other way around.

Comment: Maybe [look the other way around](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=vnc-server&c=apps)? Those VNC servers for Android bring the Android screens to (a VNC client on) the desktop. In case it matters, [VMLite VNC Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vmlite.vncserver)  is one not requiring root (according to its description).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Droid@Screen](http://blog.ribomation.com/droid-at-screen/) for this.

If you have root access, you can use [androidscreencast](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/) as well. Hope this helps.