# how can i stream my screen to an xbmc mediastation?

Tags: screen, streaming, screen-sharing

I have 4 kids and just one tablet.
to avoid them all hanging over each other trying to see the game I would like to be able to project the screen to my Television.
I have a XBMC media station.
What is the best way to do this ?

the tablet is a p7500 ( galaxy tab 10.1 ) with cyanogenmod 10.1 on it

Thanks

Comment: Do your TV and your tablet have HDMI ports? In that case, the easiest way would be to connect them using a HDMI cable, which then would "mirror" your screen contents to your TV.

Comment: nope. TV had all filled up and for the tablet i haven't got the adapter.

Comment: Umm? What "all filled up", and what adapter? There are cables for miniHDMI-to-HDMI. I simply plugged the mini-end to my Android device, and the other end to my TV. Worked out-of-the-box.

Comment: Your right but than I have to buy a adapter. I'm looking for a software solution by wifi.

Comment: Good luck! If you find any, don't forget to let us know. My cable is not long enough to reach my couch :)

Comment: PS: Might be worth taking a look at [How do I project the screen of my android phone for a presentation?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5652/16575)