# Screen mirroring with ASUS ME172 over HDMI

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, hdmi

I have ASUS ME172 tablet with Android 4.1 and an HDMI cable, and I want to project the tablet screen to my laptop. However, when I connect the cable with laptop it doesn't do anything. I didn't find any option for HDMI on the tablet. Is there a way to control the HDMI output?

Comment: Are you using some kind of adapter? The HDMI port on your laptop is almost certainly HDMI **out** not HDMI **in**. You can't plug things into the laptop that way and display them on the screen.

Comment: you are right , the laptop HDMI is out port.
now how I can to mirror my ASUS tablet by USB?
is there any PC program or android app?

Comment: Related: [How do I project the screen of my Android phone for a presentation?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/how-do-i-project-the-screen-of-my-android-phone-for-a-presentation)  Also, take a look at the [screencast](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screencast) tag.