# Mirror device screen to pc

Tags: screen-mirroring

For presentation purposes I want to mirror the device screen to a (very large) screen connected to a pc, so multiple people can see it at the same time.

What is the best way to do this. I have seen some apps but they either require rooting, signing up for accounts etc.. I don't mind buying some cable if they exist but chromecast is a bit excessive (need to switch device often and don't always run the presentation on the same pc).

Any suggestions or hints to get me in the right directions would be much appreciated.

Comment: It has to run on multiple devices. For my current project I am testing on an asus phonepad 7 but this changes from time to time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I project the screen of my Android phone for a presentation?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/how-do-i-project-the-screen-of-my-android-phone-for-a-presentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Vysor.  You can control your phone from your computer.  Root is NOT required.

[Link to information on Vysor](http://www.vysor.io/)

1. You'll need the Android SDK install on the computer, as it does use adb, so you'll want to start adb by opening a command propmpt window and typing:

   ```
   start adb-server
   ```
2. You'll have to install the Google Chrome extension from [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor-beta/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm?authuser=1).  It only works in Google Chrome.
3. You'll need USB Debugging enabled on your phone, Settings → Developer Options.
4. Plug in your phone, and Vysor will start up automatically, and a window will open, which will be a welcome screen, shown here:

   <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

   [image: IMG:]
5. From here, you can use your mouse to swipe your homescreen left/right, take screenshots, click to open folders/apps, even keyboard access.

Comment: Nice this worked right away without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try AllCast witch only require a working Wi-Fi connection.

It works pretty great for me (LG G3, Android 5.0) :

---

1. Download [Mirror Beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.mirror)
2. On your PC, in Chrome, install [AllCast Receiver](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allcast-receiver/hjbljnpdahefgnopeohlaeohgkiidnoe)

---

Make sure both your phone and laptop are connected on the same wireless network and then :

3. Open Mirror Beta and select your computer :

[image]
[image]

AllCast Receiver will show up on your computer mirroring your Android screen.

Hope this will work for what you need.

Comment: The app for this solution keeps getting stuck on downloading without actually doing something so I couldn't test it. Also you mention both needing to be on the same wifi, but I need to display it on a pc which doesn't use wifi. Is it still possible then? I'll try downloading the app again later.

Comment: Oh ok if the PC does not have a Wi-Fi connection it won't work. Glad you found a solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

You also can use simple and cool tool [droid-at-screen](http://droid-at-screen.org/).

[image]