# Is it possible to stream computer screen to an android phone via USB?

Tags: usb, remote-access, remote-control

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to use USB debugging on an android phone to view a computer screen. (Not the other way around). I've played with Chrome remote desktop, which uses wifi, and splashtop, which promises to be wired but fails to even run. Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Well, that made me curious now :). I don't know if it is currently possible, but you would certainly need an app for that...

Comment: Yeah! I've just tested Apowermirror, it seems that USB connecting for android=>PC works, no wifi, but not the other way around for some reason. I'm guessing its cuz it doesn't seem to be something that has a big market, like why would you need a phone as a screen mirror if the computer is right there. But there are edge cases :)

Comment: USB debugging is really for PC controlling the Android device (see [`scrcpy`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207688/3573)). If you want Android app to control PC see [Izzy's list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controlpc#group_655) for RDP or VNC based solutions.