# Can I use my TV as a display for a tty while using my Android screen as a virtual keyboard?

Tags: termux, screencast, vnc

I use Termux on a rooted device to run Alpine Linux in a chroot, but since the screen is small it is hard to type with a virtual keyboard + get a good view.

I want to use my Android's screen for the keyboard while using my TV's screen as a display for a terminal. The TV in question supports VNC and Miracast.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I project the screen of my Android phone for a presentation?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/how-do-i-project-the-screen-of-my-android-phone-for-a-presentation)

Comment: @alecxs Unfortunately I don't have access to a physical keyboard.

Comment: @alecxs Can I use screenrecord/miracast with a custom resolution? I just need the tty instead of the Android screen and casting the Android screen has the demerit of not being able to set a custom resolution.

Comment: I understand, but since I have have an input device (virtual keyboard) + screen (television display) + system (alpine), it shouldn't be necessary to need another input device right? And after all I only need a tty which doesn't need a mouse for input

Comment: some devices have two screens (like LG Velvet) so obviously android supports dual-screen. Kindly wait for better qualified response

Comment: but let me tell you, custom screen resolution is pointless on screen mirror without physical keyboard - either virtual keyboard is too big and will cover half of screen, or it's too tiny to type! haven't found any dual-screen app btw...

Comment: LineageOS has "Force desktop mode" in developer options: *"Force experimental desktop mode on secondary displays"*